# Casting boost::shared_array<void> to boost::shared_array<int>

Tags: c++, boost, casting, smart-pointers

I have some legacy code that looks like this:

```
void* getData(DataType  dataType)
{

    switch(dataType)
    {
    case TYPE_FLOAT:
        return new float[ rows * clms ];

    case TYPE_INT:
        return new int[ rows * clms ];

    case TYPE_DOUBLE:
        return new double[ rows * clms ];
    default:
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to do this:

```
boost::shared_array < void > getData(DataType   dataType)
{

    boost::shared_array < void > theData;

    switch(dataType)
    {
    case TYPE_FLOAT:
        theData = boost::shared_array<float>(new float[ rows * clms ]);
                    break;

    case TYPE_INT:
        theData = boost::shared_array<int>(new int[ rows * clms ]);
                    break;

    case TYPE_DOUBLE:
        theData = boost::shared_array<double>(new double[ rows * clms ]);
                    break;

    default:
        break;
    }

            return theData;
}
```

But I can't get the casting right. What do I need to do to get this statement working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't just convert, because `shared_array<void>` doesn't know how to delete a `void*` pointer to an array of `int`.

You could try something like `shared_array<void>(new int[rows*clmns], checked_array_deleter<int>())`, although I haven't tested that it's right. You probably need to wrap the deleter in something that converts the parameter to `int*`.

Alternatively, since all your types are POD you could use an array of `char` and a `shared_array<char>`. Then there's no need to specify a deleter.

Btw, insert usual grumble here about this being a dodgy design. If you're referring to things by `void*`, or void smart pointers, then you're ignoring that C++ is a static-typed language for a reason. You might look at Boost.Variant, depending how your array is used.

Comment: You are close to the right answer, the deleter is already attached, the issue is that unlike in shared_ptr they do not cast because it is dangerous to do for arrays.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work with shared_array, use shared_ptr.

```
boost::shared_ptr < void > getData(DataType   dataType)
{
    boost::shared_ptr < void > theData;

    switch(dataType)
    {
    case TYPE_FLOAT:
        theData = boost::shared_ptr<float>(new float[ rows * clms ],   
           boost::checked_array_deleter<float>());
    break;

    case TYPE_INT:
        theData = boost::shared_ptr<int>(new int[ rows * clms ], 
         boost::checked_array_deleter<int>());
    break;

    case TYPE_DOUBLE:
        theData = boost::shared_array<double>(new double[ rows * clms ],
         boost::checked_array_deleter<double>());
    break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return theData; // I think will work
}
```

If that return does not work this will:

```
return boost::shared_ptr<void>(theData, theData.get());
```